# Use TouchDown event to prevent TouchUpInside event from firing

Tags: ios, events, uibutton

I've got some UIButtons which all have TouchUpInside events. A few of them also have TouchDown events. In certain circumstances I would like the code in the TouchDown event to prevent the TouchUpInside event from firing.

How can I short-circuit that event series?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag in the touch down method, and check the state of that flag in the touch up inside method to decide whether to execute its normal action or not.